# Sorting a collection of strings with special rules

Tags: c#, string, linq, sorting, collections

Preface: I stumbled across this at work and thought it was an interesting problem.

**Preface EDIT:** We already have a working solution, but I'm looking for other ways to approach this.

---

Given a collection of `string`:

```
["2015", "2016 New", "2016 Used", "2017 New", "2017 Used", "2018"]
```

I want to sort this collection in descending order by year.

However, I also want to apply a special rule, where a year containing the string `"New"` must come before the same year containing the string `"Used"`.

Expected result:

```
["2018", "2017 New", "2017 Used", "2016 New", "2016 Used", "2015"]
```

---

Assumptions:

- If the collection contains a given year string containing `"New"`, the collection will always contain that same year containing `"Used"` (and vice versa), and will never contain the year by itself.

  ```
  ["2017 New", "2017", "2016 Used", "2016"] // invalid input
  ```
- The years will be within range 1000-9999.

---

**What is the best way to approach this problem?**

---

**EDIT**:

Here's our solution:

```
var l = new[] { "2015", "2016 New", "2016 Used", "2017 New", "2017 Used", "2018" };

var sorted = l.OrderByDescending(i => i.Replace("Used", "Ased")).ToArray();
// ["2018", "2017 New", "2017 Used", "2016 New", "2016 Used", "2015"]
```

Comment: "2017 New" will be always before "2017 Used", so you can simple sort it by default sorting.

Comment: Have you even tried anything? We´re not doing your job.

Comment: @Fabio Yes but OP wants to sort in descending order.  So with the default sort it would be `2018, 2017 Used, 2017 New, etc etc`

Comment: "we end up with the expected result." so what is the problem?

Comment: @HimBromBeere added our solution, I originally had a community wiki as an answer, but was advised to delete it...

Comment: @maccettura Not neccessarily, if it answers the question and solves the problem, it´s absolutely okay, to give an answer to an own question. So I see no reason why OP should delete it. Actually SO *enourages* usrs to solve thier problems on their own.

Comment: Sorting + custom ordering = `IComparable`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would split your string and sort using that parts

```
var inputx = new string[] { "2015", "2016 New", "2016 Used", "2017 New", "2017 Used", "2018" };

var outputx = inputx.OrderByDescending(x => x.Split()[0]).ThenBy(x=>x).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

To get `"2017 New"` before `"2017"`, and `"2017"` before `"2017 Used"`:

```
string[] arr = {"2018", "2017 New", "2017", "2017 Used", "2016"}; 

arr = arr.OrderByDescending(s => s.Split()[0]).ThenBy(s => !s.EndsWith(" New")).ToArray();
```

or in-place sort might be a bit more efficient:

```
Array.Sort(arr, (a, b) => b.Split()[0].CompareTo(a.Split()[0]) + 
                    b.EndsWith(" New").CompareTo(a.EndsWith(" New")));
```